# Unicode error on response from web service using python suds

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, suds

I've seen the other threads about this issue, but I haven't seen an answer that helps me.

My issue is very similar to the person using "CJ's horrible web services" in a previous post.

I'm using python 2.5 and the suds library (version 0.4.1).  I request some records from a database through a web service.  I then try to print some of the fields of the returned records.  Some of the titles of those records contain characters that cause an exception.  The exception I get is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201d' in position 39: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My code looks like this:  (sr is a Service Request, the type of record I'm retrieving from the DB)

```
response = client.service.QuerySRByExample(input_data)
for sr in response:
    print sr.SRNumber, sr.Title
```

If I loop through the offending title using ord(), I can see that there are some double-quote characters that have code point 8220 and 8221.  These are what is causing the error (The first double-quote is at position 39 of the title string, as per the error message.)

```
... 114 111 108 108 101 114 32 65 8221 32 43 32 8220 68 67 78 ...
```

If I instead use

```
    print sr.SRNumber, sr.Title.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

I don't get the error.  It just drops the offending characters (anything with code point > 127).

Is there a better way to handle this?  It seems like I should be able to convert the utf-8 double-quotes into ascii double-quotes somehow.

The web service says it is using utf-8 enoding.  The first part of the response back from the web service is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

In the other thread, one user said he found something in the suds code and was able to fix it.  I don't know if that was incorporated into the suds library.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's just failing to print. If your terminal can handle utf-8 (Macs and most recent Linux), `print sr.Title.encode("utf-8")` should work. On Windows, I think you can try encoding with your system code page (probably cp1252) - but it might not have the necessary characters.

Upgrading to a newer version of Python might help. In 2.6 and 2.7, I can print out unicode characters without having to do anything special.

Comment: Tried it with Python 2.7. Same problem.  Tried  encode('cp1252') and now the error is gone, the double-quote characters are replaced with a vertical block.  How do I find out what my system code page is?

Comment: If your system language is English, it's probably 1252. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964654 . Maybe the console font doesn't have the smart quote characters, though. I don't use Windows, so I can't help much with that.